# $(a^n-b^n)$ bounded implies $a=b$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|a|=|b|>1$. If the sequence $(a^n-b^n)$ is bounded, then $a=b$.
Tried using polar coordinates but it didn't realy work out. Also, the formular for the difference of n-th powers doensn't seem very useful here. Any tips?

Comment: So the sequence $a^n - b^n$ is bounded, for all $n$?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris Exactly, that is, $\exists M>0$, $|a^n-b^n|\leq M,\,\forall n$.

Answer (score 1):

As $|a|=|b|, a=be^{i\theta}$ for some real $\theta$.  $a^n-b^n=a^n(1-e^{in\theta})$  The factor in parentheses cannot always be small unless $\theta=0$

Comment: I thought about it, but how do you prove the last affirmative?

Comment: If $\theta/\pi$ is irrational you have the equidistribution theorem.  If $\theta/\pi$ is rational the points it hits are equally distributed around the circle and there is a minimum distance from $1$ except when $n \theta$ is a multiple of $2\pi$

Comment: That would work, though it would require to assume the equidistribution theorem which is a pretty strong result. Don't think density would work since you need to guarantee the points don't accumulate near $2\pi$

Comment: I think you can get by with much less but it is a little hard to explain, which is why I used equidistribution.  In the irrational case you have to get out of any small interval around $0$ eventually, then there will be lots of multiples near an odd multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Makes sense, though I'm surprised how much work this proof requires....